# Is it possible to expand elements from multiple arrays using ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm working my way through angular js, and wrestling with ng-repeat and directives. It looks ng-repeat symbols aren't expanded in the attributes of directives. What I'd like to do is take two arrays `["a1", "a2", "a3"]` and `["b1", "b2", "b3"]`

My markup looks like this:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="TestController">
        <div ng-repeat="a in as">
            <h2>{{a}}</h2> <!-- Works fine. -->
            <directive-test a="test" b="test"></directive-test>
            <div ng-repeat="b in bs">
                <h3>{{b}}</h3> <!-- Works fine. -->
                <directive-test a="{{a}}" b="{{b}}"></directive-test><!-- Does not work. -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the backing javascript looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('TestController', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.as = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'];
    $scope.bs = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'];
}]);

app.directive('directiveTest', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: true,
        template:
            '<div>{{a}} by {{b}}</div>',
        controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.a = $attrs.a;
            $scope.b = $attrs.b;
        }]
    };
});
```

I'd expect the `{{a}}` and `{{b}}` to be expanded and see output like "a1 by b1", but instead, I see output like `{{a}} by {{b}}`. Is there a way to expand ng-repeat elements to use as attributes of custom directives?

[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/YbPFr/17/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$scope.$parent` instead of `$attrs` since you should access the model from `scope` rather than `attr`. And since `ng-repeat` creates new scope, you need `$parent` to access the model defined in the repeater.

```
controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    $scope.a = $scope.$parent.a; //change to $scope.$parent
    $scope.b = $scope.$parent.b; //change to $scope.$parent
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

here is my version: http://jsfiddle.net/FE3Tg/

I removed the controller and just copy `a` and `b` from the parent scope:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="TestController">
    <div ng-repeat="a in as">
      <directive-test a="a" b="'test'"></directive-test>
      <div ng-repeat="b in bs">
        <directive-test a="a" b="b"></directive-test>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.as = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'];
    $scope.bs = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'];
}]);

app.directive('directiveTest', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            a: '=',
            b: '='
        },
        template: '<div>{{a}} by {{b}}</div>',
        replace: true
    };
});
```